# Automatically update a value when inserting/removing another

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, sql-update, sql-insert

We have a table like the one below:

```
=# CREATE TABLE items (item_id INT NOT NULL, revision VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, is_newest_rev BOOLEAN NOT NULL, UNIQUE (item_id,revision));

...

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1B | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1C | t     <-note this, true
```

The above table is valid.

The following table is invalid:

```
=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1B | f     <-note this, false
      40 |       1C | t     <-note this, true
      40 |       1D | t     <-ERROR! 40 | 1C is already marked as true!
```

The following table is *also* invalid:

```
=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f
      40 |       1B | f
      40 |       1C | f <-ERROR! 40 has no true values!
```

I need to create a trigger (I think that's what it is) to automatically change the only true value in the list for that revision and item id to being false, and then add the new value specified in an insert query.

In other words I need it to match the following:

- Reject any insert queries attempting to insert `f` into the `is_newest_rev` column (only accept `t` insert queries)
- Automatically change the only instance of `t` in the table (for that item_id and revision) to `f` before adding the new value
- Deleting one or more `t` rows will automatically change the other `is_newest_rev` values (for that item_id and revision) to `t`
- Always make sure there is at least one instance of `t` for that item_id and revision (never 0, never 2, exactly 1)

Example:

```
=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f
      40 |       1B | f
      40 |       1C | t

=# INSERT INTO items VALUES (40, '1D', 't');
INSERT 0 1

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1A | f
      40 |       1B | f
      40 |       1C | f     <-
      40 |       1D | t     <- notice how 1C is now false and 1D is now true

=# DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id = '40' AND revision = '1A';
DELETE 1

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1B | f
      40 |       1C | f
      40 |       1D | t      <- note all other values stayed the same

=# DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id = '40' AND is_newest_rev = 't';
DELETE 1

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | f
     250 |       1B | t
     199 |       1F | t
      40 |       1B | f
      40 |       1C | t     <- note how 1D was removed and 1C was marked as true

=# DELETE FROM items WHERE is_newest_rev = 't';
DELETE 3

=# SELECT * FROM items;
 item_id | revision | is_newest_rev
---------+----------+---------------
     250 |       1A | t     <- 250, 1B is removed, 1A marked as true
      40 |       1B | t     <- 199, 1F completely removed, as no other 199s exist
                            <- 40, 1C is removed, 1B marked as true
```

I hope this explains enough what I'm looking for. If you need me to explain more let me know

Comment: Sounds like rather than using a column to determine which is the newest rev, you should create a function that gets the newest rev based on `item_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `revision` is always going to be a 2-char string, a simple CTE could dynamically generate the `is_latest_rev` column for you:

```
WITH latest_revs AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT(item_id) AS item_id,
              MAX(revision) as revision,
                       't' as is_newest_rev
   FROM items
   GROUP BY item_id)
SELECT i.item_id, i.revision, COALESCE(lr.newest_rev,'f')
FROM items i LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  latest_revs lr ON (i.item_id=lr.item_id AND i.revision=lr.revision)
ORDER BY item_id, revision;
```

If you just need a listing of the latest revisions, you can just do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(item_id), MAX(revision) FROM items GROUP BY item_id;
```

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com) employee